# ufw - how can i add custom rules in iptables-save syntax correctly?

Tags: networking, debian, iptables, firewall, ufw

So when i do

```
iptables -A ufw-user-forward -s 172.0.0.0/8 -d 10.0.0.0/24 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A ufw-user-forward -s 172.0.0.0/8 -d 10.0.0.0/24 -j DROP
```

one by one in terminal, it works
but when i add it to `after.rules` like so:

```
*filter
-A ufw-user-forward -s 172.0.0.0/8 -d 10.0.0.0/24 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-forward -s 172.0.0.0/8 -d 10.0.0.0/24 -j DROP
COMMIT
```

it doesnt

I already tried starting the rule including chain like so:

```
*filter
:ufw-user-forward - [0:0]
....
```

but no luck, any idea on how can i get this to work? i dont think those rules are added to iptables at all either when i add them to `after.rules` file

Comment: After adding those rules to the `after.rules`, do you re-run `ufw` to load those rules?

Comment: Yes, i tried both `ufw reload` and `sudo systemctl restart ufw`, tried rebooting aswell, but for some reason it just doesn't work

Comment: Anything in the logs? Also may be in the journal (`journalctl -u ufw` and go to the end)

Comment: Besides start/stop logs, nothing